# Angular2 ng2-fullpage.js afterload trigger in wrong context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullpage.js

I'm working with the fullpage.js for Angular 2 https://github.com/meiblorn/ng2-fullpage

I'm trying to trigger a specific method of my component when a page is loaded with this configuration :

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

...

@Input() public options:MnFullpageOptions = new MnFullpageOptions({
afterLoad: this.type
});

type(anchorLink, page_num){
this.resetPages();
console.log(page_num);

let phrase;
...
}

}
```

The "type" method is correctly triggered, but the "this" call don't work within the method. I guess it's because it's running in another context.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./NavbarComponent class NavbarComponent - inline template:2:5 caused by: this.resetPages is not a function
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the angular directive. Have you asked in their github issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a hack to do what I wanted to do but it's not very clean.

I created a hidden button which trigger the type method :

```
<button (click)="type(1);" class="hidden" id="show1"></button>
```

And I made the afterLoad event call a static function which 'click' on the button.

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

...

@Input() public options:MnFullpageOptions = new MnFullpageOptions({
afterLoad: click
});

type(page_num){
...
}

}

function click(_, index){
  eventFire(document.getElementById('show' + index), 'click');
}

function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    let evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```